# mySQL query - Use results again in same query

Tags: mysql

I actually don't have any code yet to provide..but I can give you the data I am trying to manipulate.

I am working with a set of tags/keywords.  Keywords *can be* related to another via the 'related_id' column.

So my table looks like:

keyword_tbl:
`keyword_id | keyword | related_id`

For this example, lets imagine the table is populated with the following entries

```
Entry 1:
keyword_id : 1
keyword: Marathons
related_id: 0

Entry 2:
keyword_id : 2
keyword: Boston
related_id: 1
```

As you can see, this entry of Boston, is related to Marathons via the related_id

I am working on giving the user the ability to search.  If they search for an individual term, thats easy and not the question. However, if they search for "Boston Marathon," I now am having difficulty with the query.

`SELECT * FROM keyword WHERE keyword LIKE "%boston%" OR keyword LIKE "%marathon%"`

After this initial query, i'd like to compare the results, which would be the 2 entries I detailed above.

Id like to return only the term that is related to the other.  In this case, Boston is the 'lowest' common denominator, and thus, I'd like to return it.

Imagine: Marathons -> Boston

Can this be done in a single query?

Thanks!

Comment: explain more , what u expect to have in result

Comment: @goodmood The result would be the entirety of the row for keyword_id 2 (boston).  This would be due to the fact that the `related_id` of `keyword: Boston` is related to `keyword:Marathons` and not the other way around.

Comment: if u search marathon , u want have boston in result?

Comment: Its not necessary. Down the road it might get more complex, but that functionality isn't needed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking something like this might do the trick:

```
SELECT
  a.*
FROM keyword a
JOIN keyword b
ON (a.related_id = b.keyword_id)
WHERE (a.keyword LIKE "%boston%"
       OR a.keyword LIKE "%marathon%")
AND (b.keyword LIKE "%boston%"
       OR b.keyword LIKE "%marathon%")
```

Comment: this appears to do what I need it to.  Thank you for the solution!  I assume this could be modified for more than 2 keywords as well?

Comment: It might start getting messy, but yes, with more keywords you would have more `OR ... LIKE ... ` expressions within the `WHERE` clause

Comment: This might be asking for a lot, but would you be able to add an additional example that uses 3 keywords?  So i know how to build the query variables in php?  Im pretty new to sql :X

Comment: Probably need a concrete example - not sure what you would want returned in that case - anything that matches, or still only one based on a chain of relations?

Comment: good point. It's getting complex now. The trick is figuring out how the user could screw up the search, isn't it?  Also, assuming that you might not have either(any) of the words they are querying. Is it possible to check the relation between all results, and return all the lowest common denominators?

Answer (score 0):

The below query will give you the answer
Marathons -> Boston.
IF there is a keyword that does not have a relation it will be displayed as
IceCream ->

```
SELECT resultset1.keyword,'->',IF(resultset2.keyword IS NOT NULL,resultset2.keyword,'')
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM keyword WHERE keyword LIKE "%boston%" OR keyword LIKE "%marathon%")
     as resultset1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM keyword WHERE keyword LIKE "%boston%" OR keyword LIKE "%marathon%")
as resultset2
on resultset1.keyword_id=resultset2.related_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting, I'll have to play around with this one.